# vue router with vue 2 component not working with laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

my vue components are working fine, but when i want it with vue router it unable to find the component

[image: this is the vue error i am getting]

[image: app.js code]

[image: this is a message i got when i installed vue router]

Comment: Vue.component, imports components globally for usage all over your application, in this case, I think vue-router doesn't get MyHome component, trying importing it to the app.js `import MyHome from "./components/MyHom.vue"` now in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this code

```
{path:'home,component:MyHome}
```

So the reason for the error is, there is no `MyHome` variable holding any component right. You just register your component with `Vue.Component` which directly register your component.

**Solution**

So now for solving this, As Johhn said, Import your component and store it in variable and then pass that variable to your route like below.

```
import MyHome from "./components/MyHome.vue"

{path:'home,component:MyHome}
```

Comment: pay attention ""  @Karan Sadana  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home',
      component: component:MyHome
    }]

Comment: @MahdiBahari I just show him only home path so not including that square barakets'[]'

Answer (score 1):

Try it with like below.

```
component: Vue.component("Home", require("./Myhome").default)
```

You don't need to import it with this way.

Hope it helps.